# AWS SES Client - ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy url

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm using an AWS Lambda function to send emails to a business user. I have http and https proxies configured in the environment variables of the function.

I use the ses client to send emails to the user, using the send_raw_email function. Sometimes this succeeds and the email is sent. Other times the email fails to send and I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://PROXY.PROXY.net:PORT"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/EmailHelper.py", line 34, in send_email
    result = self.ses_client.send_raw_email(Source=from_email, Destinations=[to_email, from_email],
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 415, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 731, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "/opt/python/botocore/client.py", line 751, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 107, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 183, in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 305, in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/opt/python/botocore/hooks.py", line 358, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/hooks.py", line 229, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/hooks.py", line 212, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 194, in __call__
    if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):
  File "/opt/python/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 267, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
  File "/opt/python/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 294, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 333, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
  File "/opt/python/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 233, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
  File "/opt/python/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 376, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/endpoint.py", line 321, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/opt/python/botocore/httpsession.py", line 470, in send
    raise ProxyConnectionError(proxy_url=mask_proxy_url(proxy_url), error=e)
```

Does anyone know why this kind of error occurs? I'm struggling to find any guidance in the AWS Docs and I'm finding it strange that sometimes it succeeds and sends the email and other times it fails.